# Any modern phones with display, where picture is visible even when backlight is off?

Tags: smartphones, mobile-phone

I still use Siemens CX70 from 2005 and Nokia phone from 2006 exactly for their ability to show what's on screen even when backlight is off (I need to see the clock and calendar without pressing any buttons, it's just lies before me, and I write time and date from it to journal many times per day). Sadly, these phones features in 2024 are too poor. I want Internet access at least.

[image]

I know, AMOLED phones can display date and time, but they quickly discharge battery in such mode.

Maybe someone know some modern phone with Internet browser, but also with such awesome screen? It could be button-phone, it could be flip phone with two screens, but one screen should always display date and time (Most of them turn it off.).

I saw many flip phones, like Gigaset GL7, Philips Xenium E2602, others. But the date and time screen turns off after certain amount of time.

Comment: Have you considered using a separate device than your phone for this time recording task you do?

Comment: Power consumption on OLED devices can actually be quite low, since black pixels don't draw any power; if you have a relatively small, relatively dim clock as your lock screen, it's not going to take an insane amount of power even if it's always on. If that's not enough though, I'd recommend the Hisense A6: it's a dual display phone, with an OLED and an e-ink display. It's not a perfect phone, but it's almost totally unique in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

A phone with an e-Ink display might suit your needs best.
That means that the contents of the screen don't change even when the display is powered off and it only consumes power when the displayed contents change.

HiSense seems to manufacture such phones, such as the HiSense A9 Pro.
Mudita and TCL also offer devices.

Comment: Whoa, thank you. I didn't knew such phones already in production. It's cost high, through...